# Multipart/form-data not working on axios put request

Tags: laravel, next.js, axios, swr

I am now trying to make a crud functionality with file upload on my project. I have done the creation part and it's all working fine since I implemented that with `new FormData()` by appending the file value and sending `post` request from axios with headers `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`.

However, axios sends an empty body if I pass `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` in the headers. If I remove it, it sends the actual object but without the uploaded file. I am implementing this on NextJs with Laravel backend.

Here's the code

```
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('first_name', values.first_name);
      formData.append('last_name', values.last_name);
      formData.append('phone_no', values.phone_no);
      formData.append('profile_picture', values.profile_picture, 'bermuda.png');
      formData.append('password', values.password);

      await axios
        .put(`/api/v1/users/${user.member_no}`, formData, 
         {
           headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
         })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);
          if (res.status === 201) {
            toast.success('Member updated successfully.');

            refreshUser(); // mutating the swr request
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          toast.error(err.response.data.message);
        });

      setLoading(false);
    },
```

`console.log(res.data)` from axios returns [] if I pass multipart/form-data or it returns the whole value object if i remove it but wihout the uploaded file.

Comment: This is a known problem that has been around since Laravel 5.x, I'm not exactly sure why this is happening but a workaround is to change your request type to POST and add a `_method` field with the value `put`, Laravel automatically recognizes that as a PUT request.

Comment: Where should I write that '_method' with 'put' value on axios request? Is that on the headers or options object?

Comment: it'd be within your formData, try to append that value through `formData.append('_method', 'put');`  and change your axios request to post, then let me know if the workaround worked for you.

Comment: @Mike, I just tried as you mentioned and it works. Thank you so much. Can you please comment above suggestion as an answer so that I could tick it as the best answer?

Comment: Done, here's hoping somebody will actually look into this problem and why it is the way it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be a common re-occurring problem within Laravel projects. Not sure if it's caused by Axios or Laravel itself, but for the meantime, the following workaround works:

Instead of sending an actual HTTP PUT request, send an HTTP POST request with a parameter in your formData named `_method` with its value set to `put`. This is a feature in Laravel known as [method spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#form-method-spoofing).

Adding that field to your formData, your code would look like this:

```js
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('_method', 'put');
      formData.append('first_name', values.first_name);
      formData.append('last_name', values.last_name);
      formData.append('phone_no', values.phone_no);
      formData.append('profile_picture', values.profile_picture, 'bermuda.png');
      formData.append('password', values.password);

      await axios
        .post(`/api/v1/users/${user.member_no}`, formData, 
         {
           headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
         })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);
          if (res.status === 201) {
            toast.success('Member updated successfully.');

            refreshUser(); // mutating the swr request
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          toast.error(err.response.data.message);
        });

      setLoading(false);
    },
```